# Оброк, обирать?

Tags: этимология, славянизмы

[3Мак.5:2](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006.pdf)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"...и повеле въ грядущии день изобилне накормити слоны оброки плода ливанъска..."

Слово оброк этимологически от глагола обирать?

Answer (score 1):

> Слово оброк этимологически от глагола обирать?

Нет. Не надо ставить телегу впереди лошади. Не может короткое древнее существительное происходить от "длинного" глагола с новоделом-суффиксом.

> Тогда (царь) тяжце исполнен гнева и ярости, весьма непременен, призвав
>   ермона слономъ началника, повеле во грядущий день изобилне накормити
>   слоны рукоятьми ливанскими и виномъ многим несмешеным всех напоити,
>   ихже бе числом пять сот, и разсверепевших от вина нещадно даннаго
>   повести во сретение смерти иудейския.

МАК3:5.1

Здесь речь о плодах, можно связать с "обирают", но в значении церковнославянском, то есть оброк близко к "сбор", "урожай", "плод" и т.д.

Современное "обирать" (тоже кстати, устаревающее) это значение потеряло вовсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, в ожеговском словаре _обирать_ в первом значении таки связано с деревьями.

Comment: @Aer Да?! Любопытно, но к вопросу отношения прямого не имеет. Оброк - слово вообще праслявянское, а глагольные суффиксы типа "ира" - это уже почти что современность. так что с этимологией тут явно не в ту степь.

Comment: Оффтопик:
Это лично мое мнение, по-моему, на первых порах, в советское время не шипко жаловали этимологической отсылкой к духовным источникам, так как этимологические словари также несли "воспитательную" функцию, при этом, по моему личному мнению, в царской России, в свою очередь, могли не шипко жаловать этимологической отсылкой к апокрифическим/неканоническим источникам,  к коим и относится Третья книга Маккавейская

Comment: @behemothus почти что современность это какой год?)

Comment: @prostorech еще спросите, какого числа и в котором часу. ))) Думаю, XVI-XVII век это, никак не раньше.  А то и XVIII.

Comment: *Оффтопик: Это лично мое мнение* - это именно то, что мне надо знать?!

Comment: Острожская библия 1581 (и это дата печати)

Comment: @behemothus А насчет прикрепления скриншота не уверен, книга всё-таки ©

Comment: @prostorech *А насчет прикрепления скриншота не уверен, книга всё-таки* Я уверен, что мне ваш злотстный флуд начинает надоедать.

Comment: *Острожская библия 1581 (и это дата печати)* - Вы хорошо помните,  о чем меня спрашивали?!

Comment: @behemothus "а глагольные суффиксы типа "ира" - это уже почти что современность (А то и XVIII.)"
избрать избирать
попрать попирать
пожирать
назирать
озирать
собирать
умирать
простирать
раздирать
побирать
обирать и т.п. 
всё вышеперечисленное присутствует в Острожской библии

Comment: А вы хорошо уверены, что знаете, что такое суффикс? Например в "умирать"? ))) ладно, это уже какой-то абсурд начался, да и движок рунается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90339/discussion-between-behemothus-and-prostorech).